# Accessing network.ned parameters in .cc file Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I am new in omnet. I need to access the network parameters to use it in `sensornode.cc` file. Because I uniformly distribute the node `wrt` user input. I mean I want to check the range of distribution with network parameter such as width and height.

I tried `cPar` but it failed because parameters are not defined in `sensornode.ned`. So, how can I access this parameter inside `sonsornode.cc`.

```
rng =par("range");
widthInCC =par("width");
if(rng>widthInCC+1)
rng=widthInCC+1;
snX=uniform(0,rng);
snY=uniform(0,rng);
```

`simple SensorNode` 
`{`
   `parameters:`
          `double range @unit(m);`

```
gates:
    inout snsGate[] @loose;
```

`}`

Comment: StackOverflow is all about collecting good answers to (good) questions. Your question is actually asking 2 different things, which makes it hard to identify a good answer. Would you mind asking only one question at a time? In doing so, please phrase your question so that it (along with an answer) is helpful to as many readers as possible. Thanks!

Comment: This code section, you have posted, is from your sensornode.cc file? can you post your sensornode.ned file too?

Comment: I added the sensornode.ned file but I dont want to access its parameters.Because I can already access it. I want to access network.ned parameter in sensornode.cc file.Network.ned is the basenetwork.So, All the nodes are deployed in this layer.I hope,I explained well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get a pointer to the network module and then you can get that parameter, too.

```
int width = getParentModule()->par("width");
```

Comment: Still doesnt not work. `sn.cc:19:29: error: 'getSystemModule' was not declared in this scope ` @Rudi

Comment: Probably it's better to use just the getParent(). That way you can acess the parent module's parameter. I would point out though that accessing an other module's parameter is bad software design and an anti-pattern as it prevents the later re-use of the components.

Comment: I solved the problem.I used  getParentModule() instead of getSystemModule().Thanks